# How to ask my manager for more information about a new project before I commit to relocating for it?

Tags: email, manager, projects

My manager has asked me if I am willing to work in a new project which starts shortly.  My issue is that he hasn't given me any information about the project except for the project name.  He has also asked me if I'm willing to relocate.  I need to know more details about the project before I agree to relocation.
How can I ask him to share the project requirements with me?

Comment: What's wrong with just asking? "Dear Mr. Manager, that sounds interesting. Are there any details available yet for the project? Regards, John Doe".

Comment: That's a tough one with some managers. Some of them will require an answer, a definitive one, before giving more details...

Comment: If the manager can't get you more details, then he can't expect you to relocate.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Sometimes you know projects that will go somewhere, and projects that won't. If you think that project is a stupid idea and will be cancelled in six months time, you are not going to relocate for it. If you think that project will make millions and will be good for your career, then you relocate. (Works both ways. If an employee thinks the project is a stupid idea, you wouldn't want them on that team).

Answer (score 16):

I'd go with something like this:

> Hi Manager
>
> I'd like to hear more about the project before I commit to relocating.
>   Whatever details you are able to make available will help me make my
>   decision.
>
> Thanks 
>   Nandhini